# How to assign the size of a two dimensional array at run time?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a two dimensional array defined as this

```
int[,] array1 = new int[,]{{1,0},{3,5},{2,5},{8,7}};
```

or I can input any other two dimensional array as array1, maybe

```
array1 = new int[6,2]...
```

I want to define another array2 which is a two dimensional array too, and I need array2 has the same lengths on both dimensions as array1. I cannot define array2 as

```
new int[array1.GetLength(0), array1.GetLength(1)]
```

how could I define it? If I leave it as `new int[,]` when I run below code, I get out of index exception which I think the exception makes sense.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        if (array1[i, j] == -1)
            array2[i, j] = i+j;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I got an error : A constant value is expected; but I actually run my code in a simulator IDE of visual studio. It throws such an error in my simulator...after I read your reply, I tried to run this same code in visual studio, it has no error. There must be something wrong with the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the index exception because your `new int[,]` isn't at least as big as `array1`.  Contrary to your claim, you can define array2 using the length of array1's dimensions.  Use:

```
int[,] array2 = new int[array1.GetLength(0),array1.GetLength(1)];
```

This will set `array2` to the same dimensions as `array1` and any valid element of `array1` will be valid for `array2` and so you will not get index exceptions.

Comment: Note that OP said this code does not work for them. (So some additional explanation is needed).

Comment: @spspli If this does not work for you, let me know what error you get and I can adjust the answer to address that as well.